# SecureSocial: How to programmatically log a user in?

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

I use SecureSocial module in play framework to handle user authentication.

For a specific task, I created a custom action to handle the reset password. I wonder how to programmatically log a user in without asking a user login after password reset.